# Is it common to say "nothing ever good really is"?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

While I was listening to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nYzubZz2oIQ&feature=youtu.be&t=56) song, I came across the following sentence:

> Nothing ever good really is.

What does this sentence mean? Is this construction common?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Lyrics warning"  Song lyrics are not meant to be examples of normal spoken English or written prose.

The full expression is

> I know it ain't been easy; nothing ever good really is [easy]

It means good things are never really easy to get or achieve. However the word order is strange, the word "ever" seems to be in the wrong place.